# How to share logic between new/edit views with Ember 1.0.pre4

Tags: ember.js

In previous versions of Ember, I used a singular `PostController` to manage new/show and edit views.

But now with the separation of controllers and routes and the convention of using `post.new/post.edit/post` controllers, I'm not sure what the convention for sharing the logic across views. 
Bear in mind my edit/new routes aren't nested inside the `posts` route because the outlets aren't nested so I can't put the logic in a parent route.

- Do I override the controller in the route and use my old singular controller?
- Do I use `{{with controllers.post}}` block inside the handlebars template?
- Do I use a shared mixin between `PostNewRoute/PostEditRoute` and `PostNewController/PostEditController`?
- Do I inherit `PostEditController` from `PostNewController`?
- Wrap all the post routes inside a route who's template is simply `{{outlet}}` so I can inherit shared events?
- Something else I've missed?

I doubt there's a proper convention for this yet, but I'd like to hear how other people are doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the render helper:

https://gist.github.com/dagda1/4758119

Then you can use the model hook in the router to either create the record or retrive it in the route:

https://gist.github.com/dagda1/4758144